# How to list conversations in a messaging system

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I updated the entire question now.

I have messages table for I store user's messages. By using this table, I am able to list messages to users but I am also trying to list conversation on the left side of messages, like Facebook does.

I figured out the query that is necessary for it:

```
"SELECT correspondent, MAX(updated_at) as date FROM (SELECT sender_id as correspondent,updated_at FROM messages WHERE recipient_id = #{current_user.id} UNION ALL SELECT recipient_id as correspondent, updated_at FROM messages WHERE sender_id = #{current_user.id}) x GROUP BY correspondent ORDER BY date desc"
```

The problem is that I use find_by_sql() function to retrieve data. My question is now, how can I write this query according to Active Record?

Answer (score 0):

As you already have got the SQL query, why not just execute that to get the expected result?

```
sql_query = "SELECT correspondent, MAX(updated_at) as date FROM (SELECT sender_id as correspondent,updated_at FROM messages WHERE recipient_id = #{current_user.id} UNION ALL SELECT recipient_id as correspondent, updated_at FROM messages WHERE sender_id = #{current_user.id}) x GROUP BY correspondent ORDER BY date desc"
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_query)
# use results e.g. loop through them in your program
```

Then, you can use `results` in your Rails app according to your wish.

Comment: This isn't seem to be working. I think it is gonna be the example I gave in the link. with unions and group by etc..

Comment: by the way, the query you gave is the one I use finding out messages. I cannot find each conversation with it.

Comment: unfortunately, your question is not clear. Also, you have posted the `messages` table and also pointed an answer that also work on `messages` table. So, I got confused. Please clarify your question more and post all the required models and their associations. And, give some clear examples of what you are looking for.

Comment: sorry islam. my question actually simple, I have a messages table, which stores messages send between users. So, imagine Facebook and messages people send each other. With that table I can list messages between users. What I need is to find out conversations between users. What I mean by that is the messaging between us is one conversation. and one conversation has many messages. So, if I can find conversation, I am going to list them to user as people user have chat open with. So simply my question is how to get a list of users I have interacted with in a messaging system?

Comment: islam I changed the question, and it is much more simple now.

Comment: @cyonder look at my updated answer and let me know if that works for you.